# How can I download apps to iOS Simulator?

Tags: swift, xctest, xcuitest, xctestcase

with the recent updates appstore is not available in simulator. I want to download apps such as twitter, facebook etc... to implement some UITests. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I don’t think the App Store has ever been available in the simulator. It’s why universal links that take you to the App Store will fail on the simulator. Anyway, I don’t think you can install apps to the simulator. You just use it to build to from Xcode.

Comment: Hmm I see.. Thanks for you response. In some tutorials I saw that instructors navigate to appstore and download apps from the simulator. Thats why I asked but thanks!

Comment: Was it definitely the simulator and not a screen share of their actual device?

Comment: I am a total idiot. Yes I checked now its the actual device with screen share. Thanks!

Comment:  no worries. Glad we got it sorted. 

Comment: If you are using Mac M1 or M2, you can download the direct app from App Store on MacOS. Not working with CPU intel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only possible using a physical device. The App Store has never (as far as I know) been available in the simulator.